# Laravel id from URL to variable

Tags: php, laravel, api

I am building a basic API in Laravel for a Nuxt.js front end to interact with. I want it to be able to search for individual posts (called reels). I am unable to define the reel/post ID in the URL as a variable.

```php
Route::get('reel/{id}', [
    'middleware' => 'cors', function () {
        $query = \App\Reel::where('id', $id);

        return $query->get();
    }
]);
```

How can I get the {id} so it can be used in the contained code to search the DB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you must include every variable in the URL as a paramater on the callback

```php
Route::get('reel/{id}', ['middleware' => 'cors', function($id) {

    $query = \App\Reel::where('id', $id);
    return $query->get(); 

}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Route Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-model-binding) to automatically load your model:

```
Route::get('reel/{reel}', function (\App\Reel $reel) {
    return $reel;
});
```

If the model doesn't exists, an 404 error will be thrown automatically by Laravel. It's like magic!